STM32 Rust Embedded Linux Compiling Error: can't find crate for `core`
So this is a starter blinky project for an STM32 NUCLEO-U575ZI-Q. I'm still learning cargo/rust in general and can't crack this compiler error.
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Linux 6.8.0-40-generic
Docker Container:
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
   Compiling nb v1.1.0
   Compiling vcell v0.1.3
   Compiling void v1.0.2
   Compiling bare-metal v0.2.5
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf`

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `bare-metal` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf`

error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf`

error: could not compile `nb` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
error: aborting due to 1 previous error

error[E0463]: can't find crate for `core`
  |
  = note: the `thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf` target may not be installed
  = help: consider downloading the target with `rustup target add thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: aborting due to 1 previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0463`.
error: could not compile `void` (lib) due to 2 previous errors
error: could not compile `vcell` (lib) due to 2 previous errors

.
├── blinky
│   ├── build.rs
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── examples
│   ├── memory.x
│   ├── openocd.cfg
│   ├── openocd.gdb
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   └── target
├── devManager.sh
├── docker
│   └── Dockerfile
├── stm32u575_pac
│   ├── build.rs
│   ├── Cargo.lock
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   ├── device.x
│   ├── src
│   ├── stm32u575.svd
│   └── target
└── svd
    └── stm32u575.svd

9 directories, 15 files


The only resources I find for it are 5+ years old.
If I try hitting debug in the text editor, I get "cargo invocation has failed: Error: exit code: 101"
I already tried
rustup target add thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf

launch.json
{
    /* 
     * Requires the Rust Language Server (rust-analyzer) and Cortex-Debug extensions
     * https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer
     * https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marus25.cortex-debug
     */
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug (QEMU)",
            "servertype": "qemu",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "Cargo Build (debug)",
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "executable": "./target/thumbv7m-none-eabi/debug/blinky",
            /* Run `cargo build --example hello` and uncomment this line to run semi-hosting example */
            //"executable": "./target/thumbv7m-none-eabi/debug/examples/hello",
            "cpu": "cortex-m3",
            "machine": "lm3s6965evb",
        },
        {
            /* Configuration for the STM32F303 Discovery board */
            "type": "cortex-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug (OpenOCD)",
            "servertype": "openocd",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "Cargo Build (debug)",
            "runToEntryPoint": "main",
            "executable": "./target/thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf/debug/blinky",
            /* Run `cargo build --example itm` and uncomment this line to run itm example */
            // "executable": "./target/thumbv7em-none-eabihf/debug/examples/itm",
            "device": "STM32U575ZIT",
            "configFiles": [
                "interface/stlink-v2-1.cfg",
                "target/stm32u5x.cfg"
            ],
            "svdFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/stmu575.svd",
            "swoConfig": {
                "enabled": true,
                "cpuFrequency": 8000000,
                "swoFrequency": 2000000,
                "source": "probe",
                "decoders": [
                    { "type": "console", "label": "ITM", "port": 0 }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Dockerfile
# Use the latest version of Ubuntu as the base image
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Set the maintainer label
LABEL maintainer="dvillalva21@gmail.com"

# Set environment variables to non-interactive to prevent prompts
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=non-interactive

# Update package lists, install basic tools, toolchains, stlink-tools, and clean up in one RUN command
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    git \
    libtool \
    make \
    pkg-config \
    ca-certificates \
    software-properties-common \
    xz-utils \
    libssl-dev && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Rust using rustup
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y

# Add Rust to the PATH environment variable
ENV PATH=/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH

# cargo-binutils is a collection of Cargo subcommands that make
# it easy to use the LLVM tools that are shipped with the Rust toolchain.
# These tools include the LLVM versions of objdump, nm and size and are
# used for inspecting binaries.
# referece: https://docs.rust-embedded.org/book/intro/tooling.html
RUN cargo install cargo-binutils
RUN rustup component add llvm-tools

# cargo-generate is a developer tool to help you get up and running quickly
# with a new Rust project by leveraging a pre-existing git repository as a template.
RUN cargo install cargo-generate

# svd2rust is a tool to generate Rust register maps (structs) from SVD files.
# You can use this tool to generate a Peripheral Access Crate (PAC) for your microcontroller.
RUN cargo install svd2rust

# form is a tool to format Rust code according to a style guide.
# It is a wrapper around rustfmt and can be used to format code in a consistent manner.
RUN cargo install form
#Cortex-M33F with FPU (ARMv8-M Mainline architecture):
RUN rustup target add thumbv8m.main-none-eabihf

# Setup a tool directory in /home/dev and download the ARM toolchain
WORKDIR /home/dev
# Install GNU Arm toolchain (Version 13.2.Rel1)
RUN curl -LO https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/13.2.rel1/binrel/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz && \
    tar xf arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz && \
    rm arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi.tar.xz

# Add the GNU Arm toolchain to the PATH
ENV PATH="/home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin:${PATH}"

# Create and set the working directory to /home/app
WORKDIR /home/app
# Set the default command to bash
CMD ["/bin/bash"]

ARM Toolchain PATH: settings.json
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default High Contrast",
    "git.openRepositoryInParentFolders": "never",
    "cortex-debug.armToolchainPath": "/home/dev/arm-gnu-toolchain-13.2.rel1/bin"
}


How are you building your project? I.e. what commands do you type? And since you mention Docker, can you show us your Dockerfile?

Included in the original post :) Thanks for the help thus far.
